# How to create a merge request using Gitlab4J?

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

I made some changes to my project and commited them using JGit, I'm wokring on Gitlab! Usually when we do this manually, Gitlab generates a popup at the top of the repository that requests for the creation of a merge request. I used Gitlab4J for cloning my repositories and I noticed that there's also an API for the merge requests, does anyone knows how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, here's the code snippet:

```
GITLAB.getMergeRequestApi().createMergeRequest(
                projectIdOrPath, 
                sourceBranch, 
                targetBranch, 
                title, 
                description, 
                assigneeId)
```

If you want to recover the `projectIdOrPath` using your local repository you can add this code snippet that uses JGit and Gitlab4J ProjectApi:

```
private Project getProject(Git localRepo) throws GitLabApiException {
   return GITLAB.getProjectApi().getProjects().parallelStream()
      .filter(p -> p.getHttpUrlToRepo()
      .equals(localRepo.getRepository().getConfig().getString("remote", "origin", "url")))
      .findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

And for the `assigneeId` you can get it using this code snippet which uses the approver's username:

```
GITLAB.getUserApi().getUser(approver).getId()
```